# Tabulator: How to get the price change amount after update: data.now - cell.getOldValue = change amount?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

In Tabulator 5.4, I am trying to calculate the price change amount after each update. I am using a websocket to stream price data. I have column with current price (now), a column with previous price (nowold) and a column for the amount of change(Pdiff).

I have formatter that creates the cell.getOldValue in the column. (I tried to create a mutator, but could not get it to work).

In the Pdiff column, I can get the data.now, but nothing for the data.nowold or cell.getOldValue.

(I know I need a mutator for the old price, but could not get a mutator to work with cell.getOldValue) Help? or Would accessor work to get the old price into Pdiff?

```
         {title:"Now", field:"now",  hozAlign:"center", width: "4pt", mutateLink: 
           "Pdiff"},

          {title:"Old", field:"nowold",  hozAlign:"center", width: "4pt",
          mutateLink: "Pdiff",
          formatter:function(cell, formatterParams, onRendered){
            oldv = cell.getOldValue();
            return oldv
           }},

          {title:"PDiff ", field:"Pdiff", hozAlign:"center", width: "4pt", 
          mutator: function(value, data) {
            value = data.now - data.nowold (does not work)
            return value
          }},
```

Comment: Im not really clear on where you are stuck but you need to do `let data = cell.getData();`  then you have the row to act on. so you can access `data.nowold`.